# Why does ngModel cause infinite loops when passing new Objects, when Input doesn't?

Tags: angular

This causes an infinite loop: ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4GAM251GYrjXpU0NlWU9) - the entire page will freeze if you run this)

```
<child [ngModel]="foo()" ngDefaultControl></child>
...
foo() {return new Object();}
...
//child implements ControlValueAccessor
```

and this doesn't: ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HuZwNN4GkBGcqUsm3uvm))

```
<child [anythingElse]="foo()" ngDefaultControl></child>
...
foo() {return new Object();}
...
@Input() anythingElse; //on child
```

why does this happen? is this a bug?

Comment: What if you use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[ngModel]` ?

Comment: @trichetriche `[(ngModel)]` is for two way data binding. I'm using [property binding] here, in both the `Input` and `ngModel` scenarios. `[(ngModel)]` would just break here, since you can't assign to a expression.

Comment: This is why I ask, does the two way binding make an infinite loop ?

Comment: What do you propose I change `="foo()"` to? Simply changing to `[(ngModel)]` doesn't compile: `Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 6 in [foo()=$event]`

Comment: [Here is a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bSfudqI7HPNLKhlcRAAc) that uses `[(ngModel)]` and getters/setters on `foo` to allow passing in a new Object each time. It still causes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a bug with ngModel. See the issue on Github: [angular/angular#11097](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11097).

EDIT: My workaround for this issue is using a decorator that causes `foo()` to return the old value if the deep comparison of the new value and the old value are equal. ([gist](https://gist.github.com/uber5001/6221b1db8165a12fddafe81f116e5099))